# Why aren't varimax-rotated loadings orthogonal?

Tags: pca, factor-rotation

Start with a $n \times p$ data matrix $X$.  To simplify the notation, suppose it's already centered and standardized.  Use SVD to get the rank-$k$ principal component approximation $X \approx (U_k)(S_kV_k^T) = U_k L_k^T$ with scores $U_k$ and $p \times k$ loadings matrix $L_k$.  Varimax inserts a $k \times k$ rotation $T$ as $U_k L_k^T = (U_k T^T) (L_k T)^T$.

The loadings $L_k$ have orthogonal columns, so $L_k^T L_k = I_k$ the rank-$k$ identity matrix, and as a rotation $T$ is an orthogonal matrix and therefore unitary. [The product of a matrix with orthogonal columns and a unitary matrix should also have orthogonal columns.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1872223/is-orthogonality-of-column-vectors-preserved-after-right-multiplication-by-unita)  Specifically, borrowing some notation from the accepted answer to that question, write

$$ R = L_k T = [L_kT(1) \quad L_kT(2) \quad ... L_kT(k)] $$

Then, for $i \neq j$,
\begin{align}
\left< R(i), R(j) \right> &= (L_kT(i))^T L_kT\\
    &= T(i)^T L_k^T L_k T(j)\\
    &= T(i)^T T(j)\\
    &= 0
\end{align}
and hence the columns of the rotated loadings $L_kT$ should be orthogonal.  But this is not the case.  What am I missing?

Comment: How do you obtain $L_k^\prime L_k=I_k$?  Wouldn't that be equivalent to all singular values being equal to $1$?

Comment: Ah, that's it!  Thanks.  Happy to give you credit for the answer if you submit it as an answer.